# I'm trying to scrape a table web-site with different table option values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to scrap a table web-sites (an example is in this url: https://whalewisdom.com/filer/berkshire-hathaway-inc#tabholdings_tab_link  ). But there are different option values in this table.

In particular I Would like to set the "Quarter View" option in: Q4 2021 13F Filings

[image]

The currently code implementing are:

```
test = {}
dict_scr = {}
for ii in range (0,12):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.binary_location = r'C://Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
    driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:/\geckodriver.exe' , options=options)
    driver.execute("get", {'url': link_scr['Links'][ii]})
    test[link_scr.index[ii]] = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#current_holdings_table"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
    dict_scr[link_scr.index[ii]]  = pd.read_html(test[link_scr.index[ii]])
    print(test[link_scr.index[ii]])
```

How I can update my code for including the option value required?

Comment: I don't see your code trials to either of your questions toselect **50** or **Q1 2022 13F Filings**. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'am searching it!   How I can add this option values in my code ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To select the `<option>` with text as **Q1 2022 13F Filings** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://whalewisdom.com/filer/berkshire-hathaway-inc#tabholdings_tab_link'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.dfwid-close"))).click()
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label#qtr-1-label"))))
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#quarter_one")))).select_by_value('85')
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://whalewisdom.com/filer/berkshire-hathaway-inc#tabholdings_tab_link'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='dfwid-close']"))).click()
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[@id='qtr-1-label']"))))
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='quarter_one']")))).select_by_value('85')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: Quarter to view]

Comment: It is wrong. Python return me: "WebDriverException: Failed to write request to stream"

Comment: Nada.. the reply is:    ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <a id="dfwid-close-184302" class="dfwid-close"> is not clickable at point (857,207) because another element <span class="Text-azid7f-0 fLnYON"> obscures it

Comment: `<a id="dfwid-close-184302" class="dfwid-close">` is the close icon in Email popup which possibly isn't visible from your locale. Comment out the step if not needed or handle manually to reach to your main query.

Comment: I can only see this in html Inspect: <select id="quarter_one" class="form-control" style="min-width:175px;appearance:auto;">
                  <option value="-1">Current Combined 13F/13D/G</option>
                      <option value="85">Q1 2022 13F Filings </option>
                      <option value="84">Q4 2021 13F Filings </option>
                      <option value="83">Q3 2021 13F Filings </option>
                      <option value="82">Q2 2021 13F Filings </option>

Comment: The quastion is: how can I scraping this web site, with different option values? for example i need to scraping the first 50 rows of this table and i would like to get the oterh quarter

Comment: Comment out the secondline `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='dfwid-close']"))).click()` I'm seeing this as I'm out of Europe.

Comment: Is It Clear my question?

Comment: OK. Now the code run correctly but: How can i see the screaping dataframe? And First of All how can i Scraping the first 50 rows? (this is a option values)

Comment: Please restrict from asking multiple questions in a single discussion. Else it won't be useful to the future visitors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247059/discussion-between-agustos-imola-and-undetected-selenium).